Ubuntu 23.10 - Wifi not working
ive just did a fresh install of "Ubuntu 23.10" downloaded from the official site.
The problem is that my wifi adapter is being recognized - there are even drivers enabled for it - but when i press "network" option, there is no wifi at all.
In the "additional drivers" section is stated this:
Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
(an alternative driver is being used for this device)

Use dkms source for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver from broadcom-sta-dkms (not free)
Do not use this device

Ive tried to disable the driver then enable it again, but with no good result.
Can someone help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance... :)

Does this answer your question? How can I install Broadcom Wireless Adapter BCM4352 802.11ac PCID [14e4:43b1] (rev 03) on fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)? In case that doesn't help, try to provide more info.

So the solution is to disable "Secure Boot"? Ive tried that but the option is greyed out in BIOS... :(

So ive successfuly disabled the "Secure Boot". The wifi is now working. Should i keep it disabled from now on? Thanks

Keep Secure Boot off unless you use mokutil to sign the wl driver needed for wifi
